# Schema.org AggregateOffer with custom text (e.g. "per entree")

Tags: schema.org

I need "per entree" or "per night" written with [`AggregateOffer`](http://schema.org/AggregateOffer) or [`Offer`](http://schema.org/Offer) from schema.org.

[Google's Structured Data Testing Tool](https://www.google.com/webmasters/tools/richsnippets) shows an example if you click on "Reviews". Urbanspoon uses the text "per entree" to outline the relation to the price, but they do not work with schema.org. Does anybody know how to handle this with schema.org?